# How much RAM is actually available for applications in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel

I’m working on embedded Linux targets (32-bit ARM) and need to determine how much RAM is available for applications once the kernel and core software are launched.  Available memory reported by free and /proc/meminfo don’t seem to align with what testing shows is actually usable by applications.  Is there a way to correctly calculate how much RAM is truly available without running e.g., stress on each system?

The target system used in my tests below has 256 MB of RAM and does not use swap (CONFIG_SWAP is not set).  I’m used the 3.14.79-rt85 kernel in the tests below but have also tried 4.9.39 and see similar results.  During boot, the following is reported:

```
Memory: 183172K/262144K available (5901K kernel code, 377K rwdata, 1876K rodata, 909K init, 453K bss, 78972K reserved)
```

Once system initialization is complete and the base software is running (e.g., dhcp client, ssh server, etc.), I get the following reported values:

```
[root@host ~]# vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0      0 210016    320   7880    0    0     0     0  186  568  0  2 97  0  0

[root@host ~]# free -k
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         249616       31484      209828          68        8304      172996
Swap:             0           0           0

[root@host ~]# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:         249616 kB
MemFree:          209020 kB
MemAvailable:     172568 kB
Buffers:             712 kB
Cached:             4112 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:             4684 kB
Inactive:           2252 kB
Active(anon):       2120 kB
Inactive(anon):       68 kB
Active(file):       2564 kB
Inactive(file):     2184 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:          2120 kB
Mapped:             3256 kB
Shmem:                68 kB
Slab:              13236 kB
SReclaimable:       4260 kB
SUnreclaim:         8976 kB
KernelStack:         864 kB
PageTables:          296 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      124808 kB
Committed_AS:      47944 kB
VmallocTotal:    1810432 kB
VmallocUsed:        3668 kB
VmallocChunk:    1803712 kB

[root@host ~]# sysctl -a | grep '^vm'
vm.admin_reserve_kbytes = 7119
vm.block_dump = 0
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 10
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
vm.dirty_ratio = 20
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500
vm.drop_caches = 3
vm.extfrag_threshold = 500
vm.laptop_mode = 0
vm.legacy_va_layout = 0
vm.lowmem_reserve_ratio = 32
vm.max_map_count = 65530
vm.min_free_kbytes = 32768
vm.mmap_min_addr = 4096
vm.nr_pdflush_threads = 0
vm.oom_dump_tasks = 1
vm.oom_kill_allocating_task = 0
vm.overcommit_kbytes = 0
vm.overcommit_memory = 0
vm.overcommit_ratio = 50
vm.page-cluster = 3
vm.panic_on_oom = 0
vm.percpu_pagelist_fraction = 0
vm.scan_unevictable_pages = 0
vm.stat_interval = 1
vm.swappiness = 60
vm.user_reserve_kbytes = 7119
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 100
```

Based on the numbers above, I expected to have ~160 MiB available for future applications.  By tweaking sysctl vm.min_free_kbytes I can boost this to nearly 200 MiB since /proc/meminfo appears to take this reserve into account, but for testing I left it set as it is above.

To test how much RAM was actually available, i used the stress tool as follows:

```
stress --vm 11 --vm-bytes 10M --vm-keep --timeout 5s
```

At 110 MiB, the system remains responsive and both free and vmstat reflect the increased RAM usage.  The lowest reported free/available values are below:

```
[root@host ~]# free -k
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         249616      146580       93196          68        9840       57124
Swap:             0           0           0

[root@host ~]# vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
11  0      0  93204   1792   8048    0    0     0     0  240  679 50  0 50  0  0
```

Here is where things start to break down.  After increasing stress’ memory usage to 120 MiB - still well shy of the 168 MiB reported as available - the system freezes for the 5 seconds while stress is running.  Continuously running vmstat during the test (or as continuously as possible due to the freeze) shows:

```
[root@host ~]# vmstat 1
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 209664    724   6336    0    0     0     0  237  666  0  1 99  0  0
 3  0      0 121916   1024   6724    0    0   289     0 1088 22437  0 45 54  0  0
 1  0      0 208120   1328   7128    0    0  1652     0 4431 43519 28 22 50  0  0
```

Due to the significant increase in interrupts and IO, I’m guessing the kernel is evicting pages containing executable code and then promptly needing to read them back in from flash.  My questions are a) is this a correct assessment? and b) why would the kernel be doing this with RAM still available?

Note that if try to use a single worker with stress and claim 160 MiB of memory, the OOM gets activated and kills the test.  OOM does not trigger in the scenarios described above.